# MongoDB $sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

```
var x = {_id: {$in: something}, {$sort: {'date': 1}};
```

Trying to sort a list in an ascending order. Running Meteor with MongoDB. Without the `$sort`, the application runs well and displays everything in a list however unsorted. Tried adding sort in numerous of way but either the Meteor crash due to unexpected token OR my list/array becomes undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: at least add the actual API call to the code...

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the query object and the **[sort specifier](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers)** object, so change your query object from:

```
var x = {_id: {$in: something}, {$sort: {'date': 1}};
```

to

```
var x = { "_id": { "$in": something } }, 
    options = { "sort": { "date": 1 } };
```

which you can then use in your API call, for example:

```
// in myapp.js
Template.players.helpers({
    lowScorers: function () {
        var query = { "_id": { "$in": something } }, 
            options = { "sort": { "date": 1 } };
        return Users.find(query, options);
    }
});
```